# SVN on linux-server third author needed with tortoise-svn-ssh-client

Tags: svn, ssh, tortoisesvn, authorization

When I set up our vufind-server about a year ago I head quite a hard time fighting my way through setting up my very first SVN-server and tortoise-SVN-clients to support and work with it. Finding the "http://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto.html" seemed like an Godsend and made it all work out after a while. Especially as I was already using PGP-keys to autheticate myself at my servers (well to by honest, I was using *one* PGP key)...
So, it seemed easiest to pass on the PGP-information for the server-authentication to the colleague who was to work with me on the project and so get him the server-access.

Following the how-to I've made two different lines for the two different authors in the /home/svnuser/.ssh/authorized_keys-file also with two different pgp-keys, even though I do not remember any more were those come from...

But now I cannot figure out how to get a third author into the system.

I tried to add a new line with new data, but any edits made will always be as my name... Can anyone help?

Katharina

Comment: Well, if you use three keys to login to the same account on the server, then obviously all changes will be done in the name of that account! You have to login to _different_ accounts instead! Also for projects with several contributors using http access to svn is much more elegant that access via ssh.

Comment: If the first and second authors would not be differentiated at all, then I would understand that and be in total agreement with you, but they are seen as two different authors with no problems at all. :-(